# Crear un CSV con columnas de otro CSV

Tags: python-3.x, csv

Tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio: Crear un fichero CSV (llamado resumen.csv") que contenga todos los datos de las columnas:"available_bike_stands,available_bikes,bike_stands,contract_name,number,status" mas 2 columnas nuevas: "P_available" y "P_bikes" que son los porcentajes de las columnas available_bike_stands" y "available_bikes" sobre la columna "bike_stands" (Sin índice)
La verdad, con el material que tengo no sé como terminar el código, he hecho esto

```
import xlwt
def main():
    fichero=csv.DictReader(open('bicis_examen.csv',encoding='utf'))
    book = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet1 = book.add_sheet('PyHoja 1')
    cols = ['available_bike_stands,available_bikes,bike_stands,contract_name,number,status','P_available','P_bikes']
    for row in fichero:
```

Aquí me he parado porque estoy totalmente bloqueado, si me echan una mano se lo agradezco

Comment: Y como quieres que te ayudemos si no sabemos cual es el csv??

Answer (score 1):

Python tiene de forma nativa el [módulo csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) para manejar este tipo de archivos.

Suponiendo que tienes un `example.csv` con la siguiente información de la cual se quiere agregar otra columna con el total del precio * cantidad:

> ```
> Description,Price,Amount
> Llanta,52.89,4
> Tornillo,3.25,12
> Aceite,10.32,3
> ```

Leer el CSV y calcular el total de cada fila. Esto se acumulará en una lista, `new_data`

```
import csv

new_data = []
with open('example.csv') as cf:
    reader = csv.reader(cf, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        new_row = row[:]
        total = float(row[1]) * int(row[2])
        new_row.append(total)
        new_data.append(new_row)
```

Escribir la información en otro CSV

```
header.append('Total')
with open('resumen.csv', 'w', newline='') as cf:
    writer = csv.writer(cf, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(new_data)
```

El resultado:

```
Description,Price,Amount,Total
Llanta,52.89,4,211.56
Tornillo,3.25,12,39.0
Aceite,10.32,3,30.96
```